# Google Play Games achievements have 0xp

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, achievements

I'm currently working on adding achievements to an existing game. Achievements are not published yet.
When unlocking an achievement, we have system popup that says it gained 0xp. Every achievement have correct xp values assigned in Play Games Console UI.

Is that "0xp" thing happens because of unpublished achievements? Did anyone have this problem?

[image]

Comment: Maybe show us the code you use to update the achievement state.

Comment: There's nothing special about code. It all goes down to calling [api unlock method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/AchievementsClient#public-abstract-void-unlock-string-id), and it works just fine. As far, as I can see, there's no way to provide xp amount in code. Am I right?

Comment: This call `public abstract Task<Boolean> setStepsImmediate (String id,int numSteps)` does take steps.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Progressing and unlocking achievements works ok, no problems here.  But my question is not about steps, used for incremental achievements. It's about XP points assigned to an achievement.

Comment: You're kind of making a lot of assumptions about what the reader knows about these things. What is "XP" then in this context? I haven't touched google play achievements in many years, but I do want to help. :)

Comment: XP is a Google Play Games thing. Every achievement has some XP assigned to it, regardless of the game. XP is assigned in Google Play Console, alongside achievement name, localization, and required progress points to unlock it. 
[link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3129939?hl=en)

By the way, we got figured it out. This issue was caused by the fact, our achievements was unpublished at the time. After publishing them, everything works fine. I just wanted to reassure my assumption before going live. 

Anyway, thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was fixed after publishing achievements. Seems like unpublished achievements for a published game have this issue. Unfortunately I couldn't find any mention of this behavior on Google Play Services Guides page.